# Returning a value passed as an argument to the function while performing recursion

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to find the minimum value in a binary tree. For this, I am using a recursive method as shown :

```
int FindMinBinaryTree(struct TreeNode* root,int min)
{
    if(root!=NULL)
    {
        if(root->data<min)
        {
            min=root->data;
            printf("%d ",root->data);
        }
        min=FindMinBinaryTree(root->left,min);
        min=FindMinBinaryTree(root->right,min);
    }
    return min;
}
```

Here, I have passed INT_MAX as the argument when calling the function. This method works perfectly. However, in several texts I have found out the following implementation for finding the minimum value:

```
 int findMin(struct node* root)
{
    // Base case
    if (root == NULL)
      return INT_MAX;

    // Return minimum of 3 values:
    // 1) Root's data 2) Min in Left Subtree
    // 3) Min in right subtree
    int res = root->data;
    int lres = findMin(root->left);
    int rres = findMin(root->right);
    if (lres < res)
      res = lres;
    if (rres < res)
      res = rres;
    return res;
}
```

My question is, is it a good practice to keep returning the values passed as an argument in recursion?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's better practice to keep the interface as simple as possible.
Your `min` value is handled just as easily in the calling program.

In this case, use the second solution, but advance the coding a little.  The last few lines can be replaced with a simple use of any handy built-in `min` function (note: don't clobber built-in names with your own function.  Try renaming yours `tree_min` or some such.)

```
return min (res, lres, rres)
```

If you *must* hand-code this, use ternary functions:

```
# return the minimum of current data, left min, and right min.
child_min = (lres < rres) ? lres : rres
return (res < child_min) ? res : child_min
```